# C# regex to match emoji

Tags: c#, regex, emoji

I would like a regex to match emoji characters in C#. If it matters, it's the characters from the Windows 8 touch keyboard ie.

Comment: Apparently, the Unicode standard is working on adding some new regex properties to support this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70936276/54323

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be an Emoji-to-Unicode standard:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji#In_Unicode

So you can probably match each of the Unicode ranges. For example, to match the range from U+1F30x to U+1F5Fx you can use `[\u1F30-\u1F5F]` etc.

Comment: Does regex support 5 digit unicode characters? I'm using Expresso regex tester and it doesn't understand that these are 5 digits long.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364009/c-sharp-regular-expressions-with-uxxxxxxxx-characters-in-the-pattern

Comment: I guess it's not possible then. Those articles are dated 2008 but say that it's basically not possible to go beyond \uFFFF.

Comment: I was trying to match ✅ and  and saw this question. but answers didn't solve my problem. Finally I used this for regex pattern `\p{So}` .

Comment: @MohaMad Why don't you post it as an answer

Comment: You're right @IlyaKogan , I posted it as an answer right now, hope help other developers.

Answer (score 3):

`\p{So}|\p{Cs}\p{Cs}(\p{Cf}\p{Cs}\p{Cs})*` match all emojis I've tried and only those.

[StringInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.stringinfo) was useful to make the pattern and might be usable directly instead of regex in some cases.

The pattern uses [unicode categories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#unicode-category-or-unicode-block-p), as shown in @MohaMad's answer. Again, with comments:

```
@"(?x)           # Enable free-spacing-mode (could have used RegexOptions instead)
\p{So}           # Match OtherSymbol, like ⏸ and ✅
|\p{Cs}\p{Cs}    # OR two Surrogate
 \uD83C\p{Cs}    # with color-modifier, like  and 
                 # (Hacky special case of Multibyte Character Set? It works.)
|\p{Cs}\p{Cs}    # OR two Surrogate, like  and 
 (\p{Cf}         # followed by a Format
 \p{Cs}\p{Cs})   # and two Surrogate, like ‍ and ‍.
*                # zero or more times (I've only seen none or once.)"
```

Answer (score 2):

I used Unicode General Categories and Named Blocks for this problem and described it in a short comment below the accepted answer:

> I was trying to match ✅ and  and saw this question. but answers
> didn't solve my problem. Finally I used this for regex pattern
> `\p{So}`

for more information about Named Blocks and Unicode General Categories visit [Microsoft Regular Expression Help Topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#SupportedNamedBlocks) .

You're able to use different names for BasicLatin, ExtendedLatin, Arabic, Cyrilic and ...
Also more specific Symbols matching with `S` family, like Currency Symbols or Math Symbols.

Comment: This is the correct way, except that I couldn't match emojis using `\p{So}` (which detects symbols) but rather `\p{Cs}` (which detects surrogate characters)

Comment: `\p{Cs}` will match anything in the [Supplementary Multilingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Supplementary_Multilingual_Plane), which will include a lot of non-English text. `\p{So}` only matches 58/1179 of the `Basic_Emoji` defined by [emoji-sequences.txt](https://www.unicode.org/Public/emoji/15.0/emoji-sequences.txt).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to plug in the unicode code value to represent them:

```
Regex regEx = new Regex(@"\uXXXX\uYYYY");
```

Where `XXXX` and `YYYY` are the unicode values of the characters you're looking for (of course changing the regular expression to fit your needs).