# Regex.Replace(content, @"\p{Cs}", ""); is not removing ⏰ from string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have following string

> Join us for an AMA with @hotcrosscom ️ Friday, Dec 10th ⏰ 2PM UTC
> Moonpot's Telegram Scan the QR

and applying

```
var newContent = Regex.Replace("Join us for an AMA with @hotcrosscom ️ Friday, Dec 10th ⏰ 2PM UTC Moonpot's Telegram Scan the QR", @"\p{Cs}", "");
```

doesnt seem to remove the emoji, i thought @"\p{Cs}" would do it
I would like to remove all emojis and not just that one from content, thank you

Comment: Very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527292/c-sharp-regex-to-match-emoji), not sure if duplicate tho

Comment: Offtopic: A quick reading almost made me flag it as spam ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Right answer was "\p{So}"