# An example of how to use RGI_Emoji in a Regex

Tags: javascript, unicode, emoji

I'm currently looking at regexs and emojis, and I'd like to use [unicode property escapes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes) to simplify the task

In https://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Full_Properties, it lists a number of emoji properties  such as `Emoji` and `Emoji_Presentation` etc.

Creating a regex using these patterns works:

```js
const re = /\p{Emoji}/gu
```

The same page also lists [RGI_Emoji](https://unicode.org/reports/tr51/#def_rgi_set), which is

> The set of all emoji (characters and sequences) covered by ED-20, ED-21, ED-22, ED-23, ED-24, and ED-25.

or basic emojis, modifiers, etc, which seems to cover all use cases that I'm looking at.

However, creating a regex using this:

```js
const re = /\p{RGI_Emoji}/gu
```

Gives a `SyntaxError`:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: invalid property name in regular expression

The unicode page does mention that

> Properties marked with * are properties of strings, not just single code points.

which `RGI_Emoji` is marked as. My knowledge of unicode isn't amazing, so I'm not sure of the proper way to use this.

**Is it possible to use `RGI_Emoji` in a regex, and if so, what's the correct way to use it?**

Comment: Start from `\p{RI} \p{RI} 
| \p{Emoji} 
  ( \p{EMod} 
  | \x{FE0F} \x{20E3}? 
  | [\x{E0020}-\x{E007E}]+ \x{E007F} )?
  (\x{200D} \p{Emoji}
    ( \p{EMod} 
    | \x{FE0F} \x{20E3}? 
    | [\x{E0020}-\x{E007E}]+ \x{E007F} )?
  )*` regex for _possible emoji_ at https://unicode.org/reports/tr51/#EBNF_and_Regex ?

Answer (score 3):

**`RGI_Emoji` is not available in JavaScript yet.**
It is mentioned on top of the [Full Properties](https://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#RL2.7) table that,

> Properties marked with * are properties of strings, not just single code points.

Support for following `sequence properties` is being proposed in [proposal-regexp-unicode-sequence-properties](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-unicode-sequence-properties). The proposal is at stage 2 i.e. not part of the ECMAScript specification yet and hence not available.

```
RGI_Emoji
Basic_Emoji
Emoji_Keycap_Sequence
RGI_Emoji_Modifier_Sequence
RGI_Emoji_Flag_Sequence
RGI_Emoji_Tag_Sequence
RGI_Emoji_ZWJ_Sequence
```

To further confirm, check available `\p{UnicodeBinaryPropertyName}`'s in the latest ECMAScript [specification](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#table-binary-unicode-properties). Only following `properties of characters` related to emoji's are available:

```
Emoji
Emoji_Component
EComp
Emoji_Modifier
EMod
Emoji_Modifier_Base
EBase
Emoji_Presentation
```

---

You'll have to form a regular expression with unicode ranges covering  ED-20, ED-21, ED-22, ED-23, ED-24, and ED-25 unicode sets. Like suggested by @JosefZ in a comment.
This discussion may help [JavaScript regular expression for Unicode emoji](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43242440/15273968)

Answer (score 2):

The emoji properties were only added to UTS #18 relatively recently (mid 2020), and this involved a significant change in Unicode's properties model in that it involved formally defining for the first time properties of strings. RGI_Emoji is a binary-valued property of strings of characters. A potential issue for use of string properties in regex is that the set corresponding to a string property is potentially a **vast** number of strings. To avoid potential problems in existing implementations, UTS #18 allows for use of the syntax \m{Property_Name} for string properties. See https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Resolving_Character_Ranges_with_Strings for more information.

It's possible that the implementation you're using has not been fully updated for Rev. 21 of UTS #18, with support for all new properties, or that it requires you to use the \m syntax for string properties.

The online Unicode *UnicodeSet* utility does support enumerating string results of a regex using the RGI_Emoji property:

https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5Cp%7BRGI_Emoji%7D&g=&i=