# Surrogate Pair Detection Fails

Tags: .net, regex, unicode, f#, surrogate-pairs

I'm working on a minor side project in F# which involves porting existing C# code to F# and I've seemingly come across a difference in how regular expressions are handled between the two languages (I'm posting this to hopefully find out I am just doing something wrong).

This minor function simply detects surrogate pairs using the regular expression trick outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14326180/1346943). Here's the current implementation:

```
let isSurrogatePair input =
    Regex.IsMatch(input, "[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]")
```

If I then execute it against a known surrogate pair like this:

```
let result = isSurrogatePair "野"
printfn "%b" result
```

I get `false` in the FSI window.

If I use the equivalent C#:

```
public bool IsSurrogatePair(string input)
{
    return Regex.IsMatch(input, "[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]");
}
```

And the same input value, I (correctly) get `true` back.

Is this a true issue? Am I simply doing something wrong in my F# implementation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There appears to be a bug in how F# encodes escaped Unicode characters.
Here's from the F# Interactive (note the last two results):

```
> "\uD500".[0] |> uint16 ;;
val it : uint16 = 54528us
> "\uD700".[0] |> uint16 ;;
val it : uint16 = 55040us
> "\uD800".[0] |> uint16 ;;
val it : uint16 = 65533us
> "\uD900".[0] |> uint16 ;;
val it : uint16 = 65533us
```

Fortunately, this workaround works:

```
> let s = new System.String( [| char 0xD800 |] )
s.[0] |> uint16
;;

val s : System.String = "�"
val it : uint16 = 55296us
```

Based on that finding, I can construct a corrected (or, rather, workarounded) version of `isSurrogatePair`:

```
let isSurrogatePair input =
  let chrToStr code = new System.String( [| char code |] )
  let regex = "[" + (chrToStr 0xD800) + "-" + (chrToStr 0xDBFF) + "][" + (chrToStr 0xDC00) + "-" + (chrToStr 0xDFFF) + "]"
  Regex.IsMatch(input,  regex)
```

This version correctly returns `true` for your input.

I have just filed this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/338

Comment: For posterity: recent versions of F# have this resolved, literals do not exhibit this encoding problem anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Seems that this is a legitimate F# bug, no argument there.  Just wanted to suggest some alternative workarounds.

---

Don't embed the problem characters in the string itself, specify them using regex's normal unicode support. The regex pattern to match unicode codepoint `XXXX` is `\uXXXX`, so just escape your backslashes or use a verbatim string:

```
Regex.IsMatch(input, "[\\uD800-\\uDBFF][\\uDC00-\\uDFFF]")
// or
Regex.IsMatch(input, @"[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]")
```

---

Use built-in regex support for unicode blocks:

```
// high surrogate followed by low surrogate
Regex.IsMatch(input, @"(\p{IsHighSurrogates}|\p{IsHighPrivateUseSurrogates})\p{IsLowSurrogates}")
```

or properties

```
// 2 characters, each of which is half of a surrogate pair
// (maybe could give false-positive if both are, e.g. low-surrogates)
Regex.IsMatch(input, @"\p{Cs}{2}")
```