# C# Regex Match NOT inside self defined tags

Tags: c#, regex

I use tags in the form of

```
[[MyTag]]Some Text[[/MyTag]]
```

To find these tags within the whole text I use the following expression (this is not related to this question here, but for info):

```
\[\[(?<key>.*\w)]\](?<keyvalue>.*?)\[\[/\1\]\]
```

Now I like to match and replace only text (MYSEARCHTEXT) which is NOT inside of these self definied tags.

Example:

```
[[Tag1]]Here I don't want to replace MYSEARCHTEXT[[/Tag1]]
But here MYSEARCHTEXT (1) should be replaced. And here MYSEARCHTEXT (2) needs to be replaced too.
[[AnotherTag]]Here I don't want to replace MYSEARCHTEXT[[/AnotherTag]]
And here I need to replace MYSEARCHTEXT (3) also.
```

MYSEARCHTEXT is a word or phrase and needs to be found 3 times in this example.

Comment: what exactly is <key> and <keyvalue>?

Comment: These are just regex group names. In the example "key" is group 1 and contains "Tag1" and "keyvalue" is group 2 and contains "Here I don't want to replace MYSEARCHTEXT".

But I need all matches of MYSEARCHTEXT which are NOT inside of these Tags (there can many tags like this one in the text with different key names).

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47627127/). You can use the regex class to loop through each of the matches and then do what you need to with the remaining text (and another regex to match `MYSEARCHTEXT`) in the former group.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea that can simplify this. Use the following regular expression to match the tagged text:

```
\[.+?\][^\[\]]*?MYSEARCHTEXT[^\[\]]*?\[.+?\]\]
```

Then replace the `MYSEARCHTEXT` within the string preserving the captured groups.

Comment: Ok, maybe my fault and I did not described clear enough. I need ALL matches of "MYSEARCHTEXT" which are NOT inside of the self defined tags. Your solution captures the whole text outside of the tags. And the tags can have different names, that's why I posted the regex example I use for the case that I want to find all of these tags. I updated the initial post to make it more clear.

Comment: Aaaah ok sorry, I didn't understand correctly. I edited my answer! xD

Comment: Not yet, see my answer to jjmcc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can work? If I understood the problem correctly this will match *MYSEARCHTEXT* outside of your tags and your matches will be in the groups. This uses the [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

https://regex101.com/r/C8Kuiz/2

```
(?:\[\[Tag1.*?\/Tag1\]\])\n?(?:.*)(?=(MYSEARCHTEXT))
```

Comment: Almost, but it seems that your match is too wide, it catches only the (2) one. And we need to consider that the whole text can have many tags with different tag names.

Comment: That wasn't in your original example, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following solution that uses your pattern version with an added alternative in a `Regex.Replace` method where a match evaluator is used as the replacement argument:

```
var pat = @"(?s)(\[\[(\w+)]].*?\[\[/\2]])|MYSEARCHTEXT";
var s = "[[Tag1]]Here I don't want to replace MYSEARCHTEXT[[/Tag1]]\nBut here MYSEARCHTEXT (1) should be replaced. And here MYSEARCHTEXT (2) needs to be replaced too.\n[[AnotherTag]]Here I don't want to replace MYSEARCHTEXT[[/AnotherTag]]\nAnd here I need to replace MYSEARCHTEXT (3) also.";
var res = Regex.Replace(s, pat, m =>
            m.Groups[1].Success ? m.Groups[1].Value : "NEW_VALUE");
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/QopzKY)

Result:

```
[[Tag1]]Here I don't want to replace MYSEARCHTEXT[[/Tag1]]
But here NEW_VALUE (1) should be replaced. And here NEW_VALUE (2) needs to be replaced too.
[[AnotherTag]]Here I don't want to replace MYSEARCHTEXT[[/AnotherTag]]
And here I need to replace NEW_VALUE (3) also.
```

**Pattern details**

- `(?s)` - a `RegexOptions.Singleline` inline modifier option (a `.` matches any char now)
- `(\[\[(\w+)]].*?\[\[/\2]])` - Group 1:

  - `\[\[` - a `[[` substring
  - `(\w+)` - Group 2: one or more word chars
  - `]]` - a `]]` substring
  - `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
  - `\[\[/` - a `[[/` substring
  - `\2` - same text as captured into Group 2
  - `]]` - a literal `]]` substring
- `|` - or
- `MYSEARCHTEXT` - some pattern to replace.

When Group 1 matches (`m.Groups[1].Success ?`) this value is put back, else the `NEW_VALUE` is inserted into the resulting string.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to match both seperately as a *positive* match.
Then decide which to replace and which to write back based on which
matched. *(Someone posted this solution already, so I won't duplicate it)*

The alternative is to forego that entirely and qualify the text
in the form of a lookahead after *searchtext*.

This shows how to do it that way.

```
var pat = @"(?s)MYSEARCHTEXT(?=(?:(?!\[\[/?\w+\]\]).)*?(?:\[\[\w+\]\]|$))";
var res = Regex.Replace(s, pat, "NEW_VALUE");
```

Demo:  https://ideone.com/KOtNik

Formatted:

```
 (?s)                          # Dot-all modifier
 MYSEARCHTEXT
 (?=                           # Qualify the text with an assertion
      (?:                           # Get non-tag characters
           (?! \[\[ /? \w+ \]\] )        
           . 
      )*?
      (?:                           # Up to -
           \[\[ \w+ \]\]                 # An open tag
        |  $                             # or, end of string
      )
 )
```